# Counting the largest connecting objects/component by using bwlabel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, morphological-analysis

Suppose I have a binary image `BW` and I'm using `bwlabel` to find the connected area of 1. I want to find the largest group of this result (which is not 0) and also the location where this group is located in the picture. How to do this?

Comment: At first i didn't try anything because i'm quite new in matlab and don't know how to do this. And then i've try the below answer and know that this is work for me.

Comment: OK then you need to edit your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are several ways to accomplish that, for example histogram the content of the nonzero elements:

```
L=bwlabel(I);
[a val]=hist(L(:),1:max(L(:)))
val(a==max(a))
```

will yield the value that is most occuring

another way is to use tabulate :

```
a=tabulate(L(:))
a(a(:,2)==max(a(2:end,2)),1)
```

tabulate creates a frequency table of data in vector L(:). The information is arranged as follows:

1st column — The unique values of L

2nd column — The number of instances of each value

3rd column — The percentage of each value

etc...

Comment: thank you natan, i think tabulate will quite work but after this command "a(1,max(a(:,2)))" i got an error "Attempted to access a(1,1.60738e+06); index out of bounds because size(a)=[7711,3]." What does it means? And with tabulate, it still count zero(0)...

Comment: I've corrected that line, so it'll give the non-zero value that repeats the most... but why not use `hist`?

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't use hist because i think i better undertand tabulate than hist regarding your code ^^!